# Javascript Check in the function, if it being called directly or from an object

Tags: javascript

When called directly such as `foo2();` it should go to the else condition but if called by object `myObj` such as `myObj.foo2();` it should execute if condition.

```
function foo2() {
    let message;

//wants to check here from how the function is called? 
    if(foo2 in myObj){
        message = "hello";
    } else  {
        message = "there!";
    }
    console.log(message);
}


let myObj = {
    foo2
};


foo2();
myObj.foo2();
```

Comment: Can't you pass a parameter to differentiate them?

Comment: You could pass a parameter to the function?

Comment: Yes guys i could but i have started learning more about the trickiness of this keyword. and wanted to try something like the above example. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to tell is to check the value of `this`:

- in `foo2();` it will either be the global object `window` or `undefined`
- in `myObj.foo2();` it will be the object `myObj` itself

```js
function foo2() {
  let message;

  if (this === myObj) {
    message = "hello";
  } else {
    message = "there!";
  }

  console.log(message);
}

let myObj = { foo2 };

foo2();
myObj.foo2();
```

**Note:** This will not work in these cases:

- If the function is an arrow one as arrow functions don't have their own `this`
- If the function is bound to an object using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), the `this` inside it will always be that object
- If the function is called using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/apply), both of those can explicitly specify the `this` value to anything

Comment: Thanks that's what i was looking for. I could pass the parameter. just wanted to do it from this keyword. i was logging this keyword but myObj.foo2() it was showing {foo2: ƒ} and was not sure how to check it. It was kind of dumb though. i was expecting in the console to give me the obj name "myObj".